# SCRIPT_PATH="${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" Bad substitution

Tags: bash, variables

On Centos my script work fine. But on Debian Squeeze when I run script, I got:

```
cpfailover.sh: 30: Bad substitution
```

Line of script say:

```
SCRIPT_PATH="${BASH_SOURCE[0]}";
```

I have seen in many examples, even here, that is a correct line no. where is the problem.

Comment: Can you use "$0" instead of `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}`? AFAIK they should be the same.

Comment: @khachik: `${BASH_SOURCE[@]}` is introduced in Bash 3.0 for debugging purpose. It does not mean the same as `$0`. According to Bash manual, elements in `${BASH_SOURCE[@]}` are the *source filenames* corresponding to the elements in `${FUNCNAME[@]}`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Are you using `/bin/sh`? On Debian Squeeze, `/bin/sh` is a symlink to `/bin/dash` which does not support `${array[0]}`.

Comment: Gracias. Update system for use old bash instead dash and work fine.

Comment: Since your script depends on bash specific features I'd suggest you use /bin/bash explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to

```
SCRIPT_PATH=$0;
```

instead of

```
SCRIPT_PATH="${BASH_SOURCE[0]}";
```

Comment: could you eleborate on why you feel `$0` is "better" than `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}`?

Comment: It's POSIX /bin/sh compatible, where ${BASH_SOURCE[0]} will only work in bash. Generally, if you're not targeting multiple architectures or old operating systems, you should switch your shebang to #!/bin/bash, so you can use all of bash's features. Bear in mind that Mac OSX ships with bash 3.2, so if you're targeting it you can't use bash-4's features.

Comment: $0 returns the current working directory; ${BASH_SOURCE[0]} returns the directory in which the script is stored. You can't use $0 to replace ${BASH_SOURCE[0]}